# Removing specific word in a string in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, nltk

I'm trying to remove several words in each value of a column but nothing is happening.

```
stop_words = ["and","lang","naman","the","sa","ko","na",
              "yan","n","yang","mo","ung","ang","ako","ng",
              "ndi","pag","ba","on","un","Me","at","to",
              "is","sia","kaya","I","s","sla","dun","po","b","pro"
             ]

newdata['Verbatim'] = newdata['Verbatim'].replace(stop_words,'', inplace = True)
```

I'm trying to generate a word cloud out from the result of the replacement but I am getting the same words(that doesn't mean anything but has a lot of volumne)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use words boundaries `\b` with joined values by `|` for regex `OR`:

```
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in stop_words)
newdata['Verbatim'] = newdata['Verbatim'].str.replace(pat, '')
```

Another solution is `split` values, remove stopwords and join back with sapce in lambda function:

```
stop_words = set(stop_words)
f = lambda x: ' '.join(w for w in x.split() if not w in stop_words)
newdata['Verbatim'] = newdata['Verbatim'].apply(f)
```

**Sample**:

```
stop_words = ["and","lang","naman","the","sa","ko","na",
              "yan","n","yang","mo","ung","ang","ako","ng",
              "ndi","pag","ba","on","un","Me","at","to",
              "is","sia","kaya","I","s","sla","dun","po","b","pro"
             ]

newdata = pd.DataFrame({'Verbatim':['I love my lang','the boss come to me']})

pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in stop_words)
newdata['Verbatim1'] = newdata['Verbatim'].str.replace(pat, '')


top_words = set(stop_words)
f = lambda x: ' '.join(w for w in x.split() if not w in stop_words)
newdata['Verbatim2'] = newdata['Verbatim'].apply(f)

print (newdata)
              Verbatim       Verbatim1     Verbatim2
0       I love my lang        love my        love my
1  the boss come to me   boss come  me  boss come me
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it similar to using regex? I'm just curious and wanted to learn more

Comment: @Maku - regex is hard for me too, maybe exist some solution for avoid after replace double or more spaces or removing traling spaces. More common is used second solution.

Comment: That's okay, anyway..you did solve my problem. Thanks again!